# Update table depending on other table's value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that I will call GROUPITEMS, and ITEMS, that are as the following :

```
GROUPITEMS

ID  |  PRIORITY_MIN  |  PRIORITY_MAX

ITEMS

ID  |  ID_GROUP  |  PRIORITY
```

What I am looking for is a request updating GroupItems "PRIORITY_MIN" and "PRIORITY_MAX" checking each item's priority inside, something like that :

```
UPDATE GROUPITEMS SET PRIORITY_MIN = MIN (ITEMS.PRIORITY WHERE ID_GROUP = GROUPITEMS.ID),
PRIORITY_MAX = MAX (ITEMS.PRIORITY WHERE ID_GROUP = GROUPITEMS.ID) WHERE GROUPITEMS.ID=myGroupId;
```

Is there a possibility to do such a thing in MySQL? Hope my explaination was clear enough.

Comment: Use `join` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You can do it with subquery as below:

```
UPDATE GROUPITEMS 
SET PRIORITY_MIN = (select min(PRIORITY) from ITEMS WHERE ID_GROUP = GROUPITEMS.ID),
PRIORITY_MAX = (select max(PRIORITY) from ITEMS WHERE ID_GROUP = GROUPITEMS.ID);
```

using join:
You can also update any table by joining it with other tables. In this scenario I have joined table `groupitems` with a sub query which is calculating max and min priority from items table for each group.

```
select id_group,min(priority) minpriority ,max(priority)maxpriority from  items
    group by id_group
```

Then through joining I have selected minpriority and maxpriority from this result set to update priority_min and priority_max of groupitems table by joining them with `t.id_group=groupitems.id` condition.

```
update groupitems
inner join 
(select id_group,min(priority) minpriority ,max(priority)maxpriority from  items
group by id_group)t
on t.id_group=groupitems.id
set priority_min= t.minpriority , priority_max=t.maxpriority;
```

Comment: just saw your edit. I am a bit noob on SQL. the first one I understand it, but join I don't get it yet (but it is my job to learn it). Which of the 2 syntaxes do you think is faster? In fact I will need to execute maybe on a thousand of elements, so speed is important on that point.

Comment: For thousands items I would go for first option. But since you are interested to learn. You can execute both the query with explain analyze and check the execution plan.

Comment: As a very useful debugging tip, you can first construct a select statement with columns of interest from both sides of the eventual `set` statement, i.e., old values and new values. Once you are satisfied that your select looks perfect then it is a simple matter of replacing it with `update <table expr> <actual set>` portion.

Comment: @Kazi just for information, I did make the test, the join method is slower than the first one (from 10% to 50% more time). Thanks again for interesting examples, I think I may look further about joining tables in requests...